# Capture only the first word from ListBox

Tags: powershell, user-interface, variables, listbox, printers

I'm writing a script that allows users to connect a network printer to their computer.

I have a ListBox which lists all printers name (like PR01, SC12,...). By choosing one and pressing the "Add"-Button, the name of the printer will be saved in a variable ($x) and it automatically runs in background.

Now I also want to add the saved comments on my printerserver on every printer in the ListBox. The problem is, by choosing a printer, it'll save the name AND also the comment in the $x variable.

Is there a way to just capture the first word?

Comment: Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: Powershell Windows Forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this as simple as splitting the string and selecting the first element?

```
H:>$s = 'PR01 In the break room'
H:>$s.split()[0]
PR01
```